# Devextreme : FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, devextreme

Trying to upgrade devextreme version 16.1.7 to 16.2.4 in an angular2 application. 'npm build' fails with error 'FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory'

Error details as follows

```
     <--- Last few GCs --->
      169161 ms: Mark-sweep 1268.1 (1413.2) -> 1268.1 (1424.2) MB, 1402.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
      170593 ms: Mark-sweep 1268.1 (1424.2) -> 1268.1 (1424.2) MB, 1431.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
      171955 ms: Mark-sweep 1268.1 (1424.2) -> 1277.1 (1413.2) MB, 1361.6 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
      173350 ms: Mark-sweep 1277.1 (1413.2) -> 1286.1 (1413.2) MB, 1394.4 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
    <--- JS stacktrace --->
    ==== JS stack trace =========================================
    Security context: 000002971F8CFB49 <JS Object>
        2: _serializeMappings(aka SourceMapGenerator_serializeMappings) [D:\WorkSpaces\updated to 16.2.4\eln-data-management\src\client\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:~291] [pc=0000005A37AF467F] (this=0000022768C27969 <a SourceMapGenerator with map 0000023BE9EFB481>)
        3: toJSON(aka SourceMapGenerator_toJSON) [D:\WorkSpaces\updated to 16.2.4\eln-data-management\src\client\n...
    FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 3
    npm ERR! app@0.0.0 build: `rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail`
    npm ERR! Exit status 3
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 build script 'rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the app package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

Using webpack1 to build the app.

```
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
  /**
   * Config
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
   * This is the object where all configuration gets set
   */
  var config = {};

  /**
   * Devtool
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
   * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
   */
  if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  } 
  else if (isTest) {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
  }
  else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  }

  // add debug messages
  config.debug = !isProd || !isTest;

  /**
   * Entry
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
   */
  config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
  };

  /**
   * Output
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
   */
  config.output = isTest ? {} : {
    path: root('dist'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8082/',
    filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
  };

  /**
   * Resolve
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  config.resolve = {
    cache: !isTest,
    root: root(),
    // only discover files that have those extensions
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    alias: {
      'app': 'src/app',
      'common': 'src/common'
    }
  };

  var atlOptions = '';
  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
    atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
  } 

  /**
   * Loaders
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
   * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
   */
  config.module = {
    preLoaders: isTest ? [] : [{test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint'}],
    loaders: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
        exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      },

      // copy those assets to output
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'
      },

      // Support for *.json files.
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss')
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.css$/, include: root('src', 'app'), loader: 'raw!postcss'},

      // support for .html as raw text
      // todo: change the loader to something that adds a hash to images
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw',  exclude: root('src', 'public')}
    ],
    postLoaders: []
  };

  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
    config.module.postLoaders.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      include: path.resolve('src'),
      loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
      exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
    });
  }

  /**
   * Plugins
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
   */
  config.plugins = [
    // Define env variables to help with builds
    // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // Environment helpers
      'process.env': {
        ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),    
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
    })
  ];

  if (!isTest && !isProd) {
      config.plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());
  }

  if (!isTest) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Generate common chunks if necessary
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),

      // Inject script and link tags into html files
      // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/public/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),

      // Extract css files
      // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
      new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].[hash].css', {disable: !isProd})
    );
  }

  // Add build specific plugins
  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
      // Only emit files when there are no errors
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
      // Dedupe modules in the output
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
      // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        mangle: { keep_fnames: true },
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
        },
      }),

      // Copy assets from the public folder
      // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: root('src/public')
      }])
    );
  }

  /**
   * PostCSS
   * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
   * Add vendor prefixes to your css
   */
  config.postcss = [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 version']
    })
  ];

  /**
   * Sass
   * Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
   * Transforms .scss files to .css
   */
  config.sassLoader = {
    //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
  };

  /**
   * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
   * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
   */
  config.tslint = {
    emitErrors: false,
    failOnHint: false
  };
      /**
   * Dev server configuration
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
   */
  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };

  return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

tsconfig as follows

```
       {
          "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "es5",
            "module": "commonjs",
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "noEmitHelpers": true,
            "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]
          },
          "compileOnSave": false,
          "buildOnSave": false,
          "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
            "forkChecker": true,
            "useWebpackText": true
          }  
        }
```

What's causing this error on upgrading to devextreme 16.2.x. App works and builds ok with devextreme 16.1.7.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with windows environment, we need to allocate more memory in webpack/node process

in node_modules/.bin/webpack.cmd (set 8GB of memory)

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
"%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
) ELSE (
@SETLOCAL
@SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
node --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
)
```

[Thanks to Angelminster who provided the help](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/447)