# NodeJS - FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, mean-stack

I am having this problem... I am using Windows 7 and Chrome.

I have tried this solution:
[FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094420/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory)

But didn't work.

Also tried this other:
[Devextreme : FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680768/devextreme-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javascript-hea)

But I cannot find that file, like if it doesn't exist.

1. I am trying to do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpXHjFb7lz8&index=4&list=PLf3Ulvd7b1B1V5MjYiv-j-_AuhOsrV4Hx) tutorial.
2. The code I am executing is this:

```js
var http = require("http"),
fs = require("fs");        

http.createServer(function(req, res){

    fs.readFile("./index_ASYNC.html", function(err, html){    
        var i=0;

        while(true) {    
            i++;    
            res.write(i+""); // Envía respuestas al navegador.
        }

        // res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

3. I execute it using **node hola_html.js**.
4. The resulting error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [5344:00000000002C05B0]    46772 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.5 (1427.9) ->
>   1399.5 (1427. 9) MB, 2231.9 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested [5344:00000000002C05B0]    49806 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.5
>   (1427.9) -> 1399.5 (1426. 9) MB, 2583.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in
>   old space requested [5344:00000000002C05B0]    52394 ms: Mark-sweep
>   1399.5 (1426.9) -> 1399.5 (1426. 9) MB, 2588.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0000028BF5325EE1 
>       1: _send [_http_outgoing.js:~216] [pc=0000002FDD52590C](this=000000B79B184D2 1 ,data=000003BB18D85CB1 ,encoding=0000010C6FF02201 ,callback=0000010C6FF02201 < null>)
>       2: /* anonymous */ [C:\Leo\Prodigios\CursoNodeJS\4-encabezados\hola_html_ASY
>   NC_v2.js:~10] [pc=0000002FDD5131F2](this=00000191E280BE21
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memo ry

5. I must add, I tried the second option I found on Internet ([Devextreme : FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680768/devextreme-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javascript-hea)) but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide example what you've tried, the exact error, and maybe how to reproduce

Comment: Edited  :D   . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously this example will cause memory leak, this line is causing it:

```
while(true) {    
   i++;    
   res.write(i+""); // Envía respuestas al navegador.
}
```

You are looping here infinitely incrementing `i` and writing to output multiple times (you should only write once).

There is no time for garbage collector to pick this up, and your RAM soon reaches its limit

I don't know language in this video but I believe author was warning about this approach.

Example application could look like this:

```
var http = require('http'); // import module
http.createServer(function (req, res) { // create http server
  // create header to let browser know what content you are trying to send
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  // write string to client
  res.write('Hello World!');
  // end the request
  res.end();
}).listen(8080); // listen to requests on http://localhost:8080
```

I see in your tutorial there are more complex examples that will work, let's say at [4:25](https://youtu.be/rpXHjFb7lz8?t=4m25s)

Comment: I can understand that making an infinite loop will make program to non stop... because is "infinite" xD  . But I wonder WHY he does it then... I will ask youtuber why... I didn't ask him because looks like he doesn't answer much...

Thank you very much anyways. If he doesn't answer me in 1 week I will give your answer like valid.

Comment: `There is no time for garbage collector to pick this up`.
I feel this is an incorrect statement.
GC doesn't wait for main thread to pause (AFAIK)
Your issue might be around this - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2970#issuecomment-141819829

Comment: There is no console here though. I didn't say it waits for event loop to be empty, too. Application overflows so quickly that there is no way for GC to pick this up, that's all.